# Outlook hangs when VBA code is pasted into thisOutlookSession

Tags: vba, outlook, freeze

Outlook freezes (mouse cursor spins in a circle) into an endless loop when VBA code is copied from Notepad++ and pasted into thisOutlookSession. It hangs but does not crash the application.

Subroutines such as event-driven Itemsend() and Application_Startup() are used in my code. I am not sure if this problem has to do with the code structure itself. Some other random codes seem to paste just fine with no hanging problems however.

Comment: Try pasting function-by-function.

Answer (score 0):

You should be to clear your code of OutlookSession and Restart your Outlook. Then try pasting function-by-function(As Paul mentioned) to check the problem. Also, you could try to change an another PC to test your code.

Related link: [Outlook Freezes with Macro](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-freezes-with-macro/8749b498-b3c9-462d-ab78-5f2f28c23f10)

Comment: None of the pasting schemes worked. However, running Outlook in safemode and back worked for good!